# When is template_name required in a ListView

Tags: django

I defined a `Horario` class in my models and I have a `horario_list.html` in my templates directory.
If I define this class, everything works fine:

```
class HorariosView(generic.ListView):
    model = Horario

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Horario.objects.all()
```

However, if I change the return type by a list, like this

```
class HorariosView(generic.ListView):
    model = Horario

    def get_queryset(self):
        return list(Horario.objects.all())
```

I get an exception `TemplateDoesNotExist`.

Now, if I add a `template_name` property in my class, everything works again:

```
class HorariosView(generic.ListView):
    model = Horario
    template_name = 'horario_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return list(Horario.objects.all())
```

When and why is `template_name` required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a real queryset, Django asks it for its `model` attribute, and constructs a template name based on that model name; see [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L165). However, a list doesn't have a `model` attribute so Django can't work out what the template should be called.

Note, you really shouldn't be returning anything other than a queryset from the `get_queryset` method anyway.

Comment: That explains the behavior. About the return type, the [doc for get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) says `Get the list of items for this view. This must be an iterable and may be a queryset (in which queryset-specific behavior will be enabled).`

Comment: On a second reading, I notice that the `template_name` thing might be one of this "queryset-specific behavior".